# Designing a streaming data pipeline for consuming events from multiple services to Hadoop

Tags: microservices, spark-streaming, flink-streaming, system-design

Let's say I have a set of microservices (let's assume 5) which are emitting events for each transaction. Let's say microservice 1 emits an INIT event with ID1. This event is consumed by the service 2 and adds its own metadata and maintaining the ID sent by the service 1. Likewise, all events flow through all the services if a transaction is successful otherwise a service that marks the transaction as failed, those events will be ignored by further services. All the events are emitted in Kafka. I wish to assign a unique id to all the events belonging to a particular transaction and stream them to Hadoop using Spark/Flink. Which one will work the best for this use case?

Also, I assume I will need a temporary cache to store all the events of a transaction for some time until a unique id is not assigned to all the events of a particular transaction. Is there a better way of doing this using a streaming engine like spark or Flink? I read about stateful streaming and windowing. Will that help here?

Comment: As far as I understood, you're implementig SAGA pattern. Could you please clarify: 1) Why you can't assign unique id per transaction on micro-service side (while emmiting)? 2) If by Hadoop you mean HDFS/S3/ADLS, than why do you need Spark/Flink? You can generate id on micro-service side and load data with Kafka connectors directly to target storage

Comment: I'm unaware of SAGA pattern, will look into it. 1) Each microservice generates its own id and commits it into its own data store, but as an event passes through each service, it assigns its own id, also maintaining id assigned by the previous service. 2) Let's just say the microservices side is already built and some bad decisions were made during that, and now its too big of a change on that front, hence using something like Spark / Flink to do this computation as the events generate in huge volume of 1 billion messages per day.

Comment: okey, if there is no way to implement that in a right way than two last questions: 1) 
What is the matching logic for same transaction events from different microservices? Are there late-arrival or duplciates? 2) how you're going to use that data in Hadoop? I'm asking because you can go different approaches here, i.e.:

Comment: a) stream logs into Hadoop, and than generate unique ids at batch process on daily basis (would be simpler to deal with duplicates, late arrivals)

Comment: b) if matching logic is simple - use AWS lambdas or Azure functions may be used instead of Spark/Flink. It depends on whether you already have Spark/Flink and if it's not an overcomplication for such a task

Comment: c) generate unique ids inside streaming app. Spark Structured is more about micro-batching and near real-time (AFAIK it has experimental real-time mode), Flink is a true streaming solution, but for such task you may go with more familiar framework.

Comment: for me option a) looks the simplest, and if it's acceptable should be preffered. Of course, if generating unique id on micro-services side isn't an option

Comment: P.S. SAGA pattern is https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html